# Reader losing values after sqlite query

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

So I'm attempting to read in values from an existing SQLite database and it seems to initially work but after the query it seems to lose the values when I try to read them in.

What am I doing wrong here?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yvj6BTjts3M

```
public ObservableCollection<Asset> GetAllAssets()
{
    _DbConn.Open();

    var command = _DbConn.CreateCommand();
    var allAssets = new ObservableCollection<Asset>();

    command.CommandText =
    @"
        SELECT * 
        FROM asset 
    ";

    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.HasRows)
        {
            Asset asset = new Asset();
            asset.AssetId = reader.GetInt32(0);
            asset.AssetTypeId = reader.GetInt32(1);
            asset.Name = reader.GetString(2);
            asset.FileLocation = reader.GetString(3);
            asset.IsCustom = reader.GetBoolean(4);
            asset.AssetSectionId = reader.GetInt32(5);
            asset.ThumbFileLocation = reader.GetString(6);

            allAssets.Add(asset);
        }
    }

    _DbConn.Close();

    return allAssets;
}
```

Comment: you should write a comment below the video, that the taught stuff does not work. And post a link to this question ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method [`HasRows()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatablereader.hasrows?view=net-5.0) returns `true` if `reader` contains one or more rows or `false` if not, but it does not advance `reader` to the next row.

You must use the method [`Read()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlDataReader_Read):

```
while (reader.Read())
......................
```